# Swashbuckle blocked by middleware authentication

Tags: .net-core, swagger, middleware

I'm creating a minimal API in dotnet 6. I have the default implementation of Swagger/Swashbuckle and everything was fine until I added a simple, custom authentication middleware (see code below).

The problem is, the middleware runs against `/swagger/index.html` which doesn't contain the API Key in the header and returns a 400 error (per the first `if` statement below). How can I fix this?

`Program.cs`

```
app.UseMiddleware<Auth>();
```

`Auth.cs`

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("ApiKey"))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("No ApiKey provided in headers");
        }

        if (!Guid.TryParse(context.Request.Headers["ApiKey"], out var apiKey))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unable to parse the ApiKey");
        }

        try
        {
            /* Look in DB for API Key yada yada yada */
        }
        catch
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
        }

        await next(context);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can exclude the path which you don't want to check for auth middleware.

something like this.

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if(!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger"))
        {
              //put your code here for checking API key in header.
        }
     }
```

also you need to return once you set the response otherwise you will get another exception.

here is the working code:

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if(!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger"))
        {
            if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("ApiKey"))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("No ApiKey provided in headers");
                return;
            }

            if (!Guid.TryParse(context.Request.Headers["ApiKey"], out var apiKey))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unable to parse the ApiKey");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                /* Look in DB for API Key yada yada yada */
            }
            catch
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
                return;
            }
        }

        await this._next(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a "correct" answer, it seems like more of a band-aid rather than an actual fix. I already implemented something similar. I would rather have the Swagger requests pass along an API key or be able to exclude those requests from authentication.

Comment: "be able to exclude those requests from authentication". Inorder to exclude requests you have to check the path you want to exclude and that what this code is doing. you can off course put up a nice way of checking path but eventually you have to check path and ignore that request for checking authentication.