# Using Fallback Authorization policy with Swagger in .Net Core 3.1 WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a .Net Core 3.1 WebApi where I am planning to use Fallback Authorization policy as a mechanism to define default authorization, whenever a controller or route does not explicitly define Authorize policy or Allow Anonymous policy. This works well for the API itself. But one problem that I run into is the Swagger UI.

Since the fallback policy gets applied to every route on the API, I get 401 error directly when I try to access Swagger UI. In .Net 5 and above, the AuthorizationHandlerContext has a resource property which is of type HttpContext. So using httpcontext, I can check for the route path and bypass Authorization for the SwaggerUI path. But in .Net Core 3.1, this resource property is always null. So I am unable to figure out how to allow anonymous access to SwaggerUI so that users can atleast browse the API documetation.

In Swagger UI registration, I am also using AppendAuthorizeToSummaryOperationFilter and AddSecurityDefinition that will force user to pass the Authorization Header, if they want to try out the API. But just for browsing the docs, I dont want apply any authorization. Any suggestions on how this can be done for .Net Core 3.1?

Thanks!

Comment: you can try with middleware check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72682810/9247039